# Set delegate between custom uiview and custom uicontrol(swift)

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

public class SelectionItem: UIView {
var radioButtonController: SSRadioButtonsController
var stepper: KWStepper!

public init(){
let gcrRadioButton = SSRadioButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
var decrementButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 400, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50))
var incrementButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 600, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50))
var countLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:500,y:100,width:50,height:50))
decrementButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "minus@2x.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
incrementButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "plus@2x.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
radioButtonController = SSRadioButtonsController(buttons: gcrRadioButton)
stepper = KWStepper(decrementButton: decrementButton, incrementButton: incrementButton)
stepper.delegate = self
stepper.valueChangedCallback = { [unowned self] stepper in
        countLabel.text = String(format: "%.f", stepper.value)
    }

    super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
    self.addSubview(gcrRadioButton)
    self.addSubview(decrementButton)
    self.addSubview(incrementButton)
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("KWStepper: NSCoding is not supported!")
}

}
```

Question: Error occur at stepper.delegate = self.  Cannot assign value of type SelectionItem to type KWStepperDelegate. KWStepper is a custom uicontrol class. How can i set delegation between two of them.

Answer (score 0):

You have the delegate set to self, but as written self does not implement the delegate protocol.  It should be:

```
public class SelectionItem: UIView, KWStepperDelegate
```

Then your SelectionItem must implement the delegate protocol.